# Python - Dynamic Time.sleep()

Tags: python, time

I want to change the sleeping time dynamically?

As of right now, its

```
secs = 60
time.sleep(secs)
```

If I want to change the sleep dynamically, ie initially it was `60 secs`, now `secs changed to 30`, and since, assuming it has already slept for 5 secs, it should now sleep for

```
30-5 = 25 secs.
```

How would I do it?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want!

Comment: Could you not start from the other side, and wait for 30s, then sleep for another 30s if necessary?

Comment: Well, what I actually want to is that the time to sleep is dynamically changing. Initially it was , say 60 secs, now it has been changed to 30 secs. So, initially it was required to sleep for 60 secs, but now since sleep time has been changed to 30 and also, it has slept for 5 secs initially, it should now has to sleep for 30-5 = 25 secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "update" the value you passed into `time.sleep()` if that's what you mean.

However, you could start at the minimum time you'd need to wait, then add more time if necessary rather than trying to take it away.

```
 secs = 30
 time.sleep(secs)
 if(condition):
     time.sleep(secs)
```

Or if you're waiting for something to complete, you could set `secs = 5` or something similar, then keep waiting 5 seconds until the condition is met.

```
secs = 5
while(not check_condition()):
    time.sleep(secs)
```

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but this should cover most cases.